# Observe lots of streams in grpc

Tags: grpc, load-balancing, grpc-java

I am trying to use grpc’s `StreamObserver` to observe and process lots of topics on a source (i.e. Salesforce). There are not many updates for each topic, but there would be lots of topics on different accounts that need to be monitored.

There would be a database that holds the list of topics that need to be monitored. All traffic would go to the same endpoint (i.e. `api.pubsub.salesforce.com:7443`) with different metadata.

The question is:

1. How do we load balance these `StreamObserver` across multiple clients?
2. How to monitor whether an individual `StreamObserver` has been stuck or not (on the client side)?

I understand there is a client load balancer. But I think that is used to balance the load on the server (by using different IPs). My case is for multiple multiple streaming connections across multiple clients.

Comment: not sure I understand the "load balancing across multiple servers" case. A server will send update on response streams which are part of existing connections from a client and there is no way to load balance at that stage. Regarding StreamObserver being stuck: do you mean the server is stuck and not sending any more responses or client is stuck while processing responses?

Comment: @SanP 
1. When I am talking about servers, they mean servers on the client side. For example, I need to subscribe to streams in Account 1...N in salesforce. And I have some servers in a cluster from A..Z that listen to those streams. I need a way that distributes these streams of 1...N to A...Z and maintain the connection. Do that make sense?
2. I mean the client is stuck. I don’t own control of the servers.